# How to Change Custom Fee order (Ascending/Descending) on cart page (woocommerce )

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In woocommerce, I have added a custom fee using the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function custom_fee_based_on_cart_total( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // The percetage
    $percent = 10; // 15%
    // The cart total
    $cart_total = $cart_object->cart_contents_total; 

    // The conditional Calculation
    $fee = $cart_total >= 25 ? $cart_total * $percent / 100 : 0;

    if ( $fee != 0 ) 
        $cart_object->add_fee( __( "Gratuity", "woocommerce" ), $fee, false );
}
```

I just want to swipe the fees order like I want "Fee per person" after the sub total and "Gratuity" after "Fee per person".

[image: here is the screenshot Attached]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the WooCommerce class WC_Cart_Fees is sorting by default the fees by amount.

reference  [WC_Cart_Fees](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart_Fees.html#17-151)

and in order to modify the default behavior of WooCommerce  you need to override 
cart-totals.php

which you can find under under woocommerce plugin dir woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php

create dir under your child theme name woocommerce/cart and the copy that file to this dir

go to line 61 which you can find the following code :

```
    <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
        <tr class="fee">
            <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

change that code to the following :

```
<?php
  $array = json_decode(json_encode(WC()->cart->get_fees()), true);
  ksort($array); // 

  foreach ($array as $fee): ?>
        <tr class="fee">
            <th><?php echo esc_html($fee['name']); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr($fee['name']); ?>"><?php echo 
  $fee['total']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

code explanation :

basicly what we have done here is geting all fees from the WC class and convert it to array using php built in function json_encode() in order to be able to sort the array in anyway we need,  i used ksort() function to sort the array based on the key in  ascending order,
and then print back the fees:

here is screenshot of the output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the *cart-fee.php* template as kashalo explained.

But if the only thing you need to change is the fee order, you can override the sort function with the `checkout_sort_fees` filter.

First example: reverse the order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_sort_fees_callback', 'reverse_sort_fees' );
function reverse_sort_fees( $order )
{
    return -$order;
}
```

You can use a more sophisticated sort, eg sort by fee name.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_sort_fees_callback', 'alpha_sort_fees', 10, 3 );
function alpha_sort_fees( $order, $a, $b )
{
    return $a->name > $b->name ? 1 : -1;
}
```